# How to accept one input for first iteration?

Tags: c

Why I need to make two inputs confirmed by "Enter" for a first iteration? How to make it to work as I expect (one input -> one enter -> next iteration)?

```
int vector[4];
for(j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    printf("Another number\n");
    printf("%d: ", j+1);
    scanf("%d\n", (vector+j));
}
```

Comment: The newline character in the format string instructs `scanf` to skip any  number of whitespace characters including none, **until the first non-whitespace character**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that you placed a `\n` character in `scanf`. This will let `scanf` to ignore any number of `\n` (or <kbd>Enter</kbd> button hit) after the input.  Remove `\n` character from `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d\n", (vector+j));  
      // ^^Remove this.
```